# Why do I see warning message in my remix browser ethereum

Tags: solidity, remix

My code is here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Hello{

    string name;
    function Hello(){
        name = "Mike";
         }
}
```

However I see this warning :

> browser/Hello.sol:6:5: Warning: No visibility specified. Defaulting to
>   "public".
>       function Hello(){
>       ^ Spanning multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, since Solidity is a smart contract language and needs to be highly auditable, a lot of warnings/errors like this are added with the idea that explicit definitions are much better than implicit definitions. In your case, it's because functions are implicitly `public` if not visibility modifier is explicitly marked. Just change it to this (unless you don't want it to be public) and the warning will go away:

```
contract Hello {
    string name;

    function Hello() public {
        name = "Mike";
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend he reads this to find out which visibility he needs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/contracts.html?highlight=visibility#visibility-and-getters.